# Naviagtion Panel is not getting loaded after login

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Navigation Pane Items are not getting loaded after logging in a user.

Here are steps:

1. Home page disply three buttons at the top of page "About", "Login" "Register"
2. Script clicks Login and inserts login id and password and click on "Sign In" button.
3. Naviagtion items should be loaded now for a Logged in User, "Logout" button should appear now. It requires multiple clicks on Login button to load page completely.

Can anyone help me here?? I have already tried deleteallcookies(). Manually cleard cache as well but did not work for me. Please have a look on code as:

```
@Test(priority=1)
      public void Login() throws Exception{
        try{
         System.out.println("test 1");
         if(driver.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("KAPx"))
         {          
//Find and click on Login button 
                         CommonFunctions.waitForElementPresentCss(driver,"a.nav-login",5);
             CommonFunctions.clickElementByCssSelector(From_Addr,To_Addr,EmailPassword,driver,"a.nav-login");
//find and insert user name
                         CommonFunctions.waitForElementPresentXpath(driver,"html/body/div[1]/div/form/fieldset/div[1]/div/input",5);
                 CommonFunctions.typeByXpath(driver,"html/body/div[1]/div/form/fieldset/div[1]/div/input",KAPxuserName);
//Find and insert password
                         CommonFunctions.waitForElementPresentXpath(driver,"html/body/div[1]/div/form/fieldset/div[2]/div/input",5);
                     CommonFunctions.typeByXpath(driver,"html/body/div[1]/div/form/fieldset/div[2]/div/input", password);
//Click on Sign In
                         CommonFunctions.waitForElementPresentXpath(driver,"html/body/div[1]/div/form/fieldset/div[4]/div/button",5);
                     CommonFunctions.clickElementByXPath(From_Addr,To_Addr,EmailPassword,driver,"html/body/div[1]/div/form/fieldset/div[4]/div/button");
//Wait for Logout to appear                     

                           CommonFunctions.waitForElementPresentXpath(driver,"LOGOUT",5);
         }
```

Comment: So it's an application problem then?!

Comment: @Arran Manually It is working fine, so does not look like an application issue...

Answer (score 0):

Try removing cache from your browser and than check result. Send me some screenshots or code snippets if problem persists.